# How to find angle of arrow in flight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geometry, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

What I want is for an arrow to shoot from an initial position (60,60) at different x and y velocities, and the angle that the bow shoots from will change depending on where the user touches the screen.

The arrow moves perfectly considering velocities and gravity, but how would I get the angle of the arrow, say if it started at a 45 degree angle shot, for the arrow to be 180 degrees when y=0? and when gravity kicks in make the head of the arrow slowly point downwards?
Also the sprite moves the arrow image from the center.

Comment: Don't you want the arrow to be pointing in the direction of travel?  (i.e. if it is falling at -45 degrees, the arrow should be pointing at -45 degrees).

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I just want the arrow to look like an actual arrow in flight rather than an arrow moving sideways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is going to be `arctan(y/x)`, starting at 0 for horizontal pointing right, to 90° pointing vertical.  Note that this is with the coordinate system having a home of 0° = directly east; make sure you add or subtract angle for how your arrow is pointed.

Comment: Thanks this worked great, except the arrow occasionally has spasms and does several 360's randomly, but I'll mess around with it and try to fix this

Comment: y and x should be the arrow's velocity values

Comment: I know, I did tan(vy/vx) and all is well, except when the initial angle is above 70'ish or below 20'ish. The arrow will just randomly spin 2-4 times around and then work fine...

Comment: You did tan or arctan?  It's possible that if you did tan, that spinning would occur.

Comment: Could be due to ambiguity of `atan(y/x)`. This will, for example, give the same result if x and y are both negative, as if x and y are both positive. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer correctly identifies the proper geometric relationship between the components of the velocity vector and its orientation, namely the arctangent function. Tim suggests computing arctangeant using `arctan(y/x)`. (Actually I think it's called `atan()` not `arctan()`?).

However, there is some ambiguity in computing arctangent using `atan()`:

- The result of `atan(y/x)` is restricted to the interval ]-90°,90°[.
- It will give the same result if x and y are both negative, as if x and y are both positive. So your arrow will always point up and to the left, never down, never right -- unless you test for the sign of x and y and apply a correction accordingly.
- Division by zero when x=0.

I don't know objective C, but most languages have an `atan2(x,y)` function which:

- returns the same as `atan(y/x)` when `x` and `y` are both positive,
- is not limited to ]-90°,90°[ but can go full circle ]-180°,180°], hence returns the correct result when `x` and/or `y` are negative,
- does not give "division by zero" when x=0, but rather correctly returns 0° or 180°.

Actually Objective C does have an `atan2()` function. If I were you, I would look up the documentation for it.

Comment: Actually `atan2` is part of C's standard library in math.h.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that the arrow should point so that it is tangent to the curve it travels on. So if the arrow's path is (x(t), y(t)) then the arrow should point in the same direction as the vector (x'(t), y'(t)) where x'(t) is the derivative of x(t). If you have x(t) and y(t) this is probably easiest.

Another way to look at it is that x'(t) is just the x component of the velocity. So if you have the velocity components vx(t) and vy(t), then the arrow should point in the same direction as the vector (vx(t), vy(t))